# Is there a way to use the includeCssFile tag to include a css file for print media?

Tags: css

`{% includeCssFile %}` can be used to add "regular" css files in the head tag. Is it possible to use this tag for print media?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `{% includeCssFile %}`, you just need to make sure and wrap all of the styles in the print stylesheet with `@media only print { }` or `@media print { }`

```
@media only print {
   nav {
       display:none;
   }
   p {
       color:#000000;
   }
   .etc {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so with `{% includeCssFile %}`, but you can use `{% includeCss %}` and have it inline.  Something like:

```
{% includeCss('
    @media print {
        p {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: red;
        }
    }
') %}
```

Comment: You can't just link to the print style sheet using `{% includeCssFile %}` and wrap the styles in `@media only print { myprintstyle1{...} }`?

Comment: Yeah, there's that too.